# How to use custom library progressbar programmatically?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar, customization

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
}
```

Am using this material design library in my project.

I wish to use a customized progressbar in it  called ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate by programmatically in a fragment as following.

```
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ll1);
        ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate progressBar = new ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate(getActivity(),null);

        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        layout.addView(progressBar);
```

But am getting an exception. Is there any mistakes in my code?
Please help me any ways to figure out the problem.

Refer this : https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary/blob/master/MaterialDesign/src/com/gc/materialdesign/views/ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate.java

The exception is

```
07-27 21:43:41.709  24071-24071/com.cook.chicken E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cook.chicken/com.cook.chicken.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate.setAttributes(ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate.java:37)
            at com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate.<init>(ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate.java:25)
            at com.cook.chicken.HomeFragment.loadingPopup(HomeFragment.java:82)
            at com.cook.chicken.HomeFragment.onActivityCreated(HomeFragment.java:75)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1178)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5213)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2087)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2139)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:143)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1241)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

Comment: What exception you are getting? Without knowing the exact exception how someone could help?

Comment: Thanks @MohammadArman for indicating. Pls check the edit.

Comment: @MohammadArman any idea?

Comment: I am putting the answer, just hold on mate. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1:**

Add the Progressbar in your Layout xml

```
<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
            android:id="@+id/progressBarCircularIndeterminate"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="#1E88E5" />
```

**Step 2:**

In your activity class:
Declare the Progressbar globally.

```
     ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate progressBarCircularIndeterminate;
```

In your **onCreate()** method:

```
     int color = getIntent().getIntExtra("BACKGROUND", Color.BLACK);
     findViewById(R.id.progressBarCircularIndetermininate).setBackgroundColor(color);
     progressBarCircularIndeterminate = (ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate) findViewById(R.id. progressBarCircularIndeterminate);
     progressTimer.start();
```

**Step 3:**

In order to start the timer you can run a separate thread like below:

```
     Thread progressTimer = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i <= 100; i++){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.sendMessage(new Message());
            }
        }
    });

    Handler handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {
        int progress = 0;
        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            progreesBarDeterminate.setProgress(progress++);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

**Note:** I have just shared the steps of the implementation. Hopefully you can modify it according to your need.